# PHP rename and concatenation adds extra numbers

Tags: php, loops, directory, rename

I have the following code which operates as follows:
option 1 renames the files in a folder with a random string
option 2 renames the files in an incremental manner.
The issue is for some reason the loop runs twice, leaving me with numbers starting from greater than 0.
Can anybody notice anything wrong with the logic?

```
if ($handle = opendir('../images/IL')) {
    $nameCount = 0;
    while (false !== ($fileName = readdir($handle))) {
        $nameCount++;
        //opt 1 for random, opt 2 numeric incremental naming

        $opt = 2;

        if( inString('.jpg', $fileName) == 'true') {
            if($opt == 1) {
            $newName = '';
            $newName = genword( 8, 5 );
            rename('../images/IL/'.$fileName, '../images/IL/'.$newName.'.jpg');
        } 
        else if ( $opt == 2 ) {
            rename('../images/IL/'.$fileName, '../images/IL/image '.$nameCount.'.jpg');             
        }
    }
closedir($handle);
}
```

Comment: the loop runs as many time as files you have. What do you mean with " for some reason the loop runs twice" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$nameCount` is being incremented on *every* iteration of the while loop. This means that `$nameCount` is incremented for files with names that do not contain ".jpg", e.g. blah.gif and this includes directories of which there are always 2: `.` the current directory, and `..` the parent directory.

So, given that `$nameCount` is immediately incremented, it's effective initial value is 1. Then add 2 for the current and parent directories. Plus any other files or directories that do not contain the substring `.jpg` - and that is why you find that the renamed files do not have the expected sequence.

Poor indentation, particularly the `$opt` if/else handling, might have contributed to this misunderstanding. Try this instead:

```
<?php
$img_dir = '../images/IL/';

function inString($needle, $haystack)
{
    if (strstr($haystack, $needle) != FALSE)
        return 'true';
    return 'false';
}

if ($handle = opendir($img_dir)) {
    $nameCount = 0;
    while (false !== ($fileName = readdir($handle))) {
        //opt 1 for random, opt 2 numeric incremental naming
        $opt = 2;

        if (inString('.jpg', $fileName) == 'true') {
            if ($opt == 1) {
                $newName = '';
                $newName = genword( 8, 5 );
                rename($img_dir.$fileName, $img_dir.$newName.'.jpg');
            }
            else if ($opt == 2) {
                $nameCount++;
                rename($img_dir.$fileName, $img_dir.$nameCount.'.jpg');
            }
        }
    }

    closedir($handle);
}
```

Note that `$nameCount` is now incremented only when a file is renamed.

Comment: Thanks for this. I spent quite some time trying to figure it out

Answer (score 1):

You do

```
$nameCount = 0;
```

before the loop and at the beginning of the loop

```
$nameCount++;
```

at the beginning of the loop. **Therefore, the files lowest number is 1.**

Comment: Yes but the loop run twice with abnormal numbering like 10.jpg, 1000.jpg, 1001.jpg n that order instead of 1, 2, 3, 4...